# OpenGL experimental missing

Tags: opengles

I'm using Raspberry Pi 4 and the OpenGL experimental is missing from raspi-config
I tried

```
sudo rpi-update
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install raspi-gpio
sudo apt-get install xcompmgr libgl1-mesa-dri
```

None works.

Comment: Look at around line 2974 in raspi-config - `Enable/disable experimental desktop GL driver` is specifically excluded on a pi4 - line 1860 in raspi-config shows you what you need to do - though, not sure it would work if the foundation specifically excluded it

Comment: Where can I find those lines?

Comment: erm, I told you, in raspi-config

Comment: and what good does it do you - it's not for the pi4, so don't do it